# listbox items as hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a ListBox that shows a list of url. I need these to be displayed as links so that when clicked they are displayed in the different browser or new tab.

Comment: And your question/problem is...?

Comment: what issue you are facing with this code?:

Answer (score 1):

To open your link your code should be like below,

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.lst.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href=this.value; ");
            // to open in new tab
            this.lst.Attributes.Add("target","_blank");

        }
```

Comment: but using this code its not going on next tab, link is opening in same tab.

Comment: I am using your code but after clicking on link why i am not going in new tab? i am getting result in same tab.